# Cannot deploy wordpress with postgres database using docker

Tags: wordpress, postgresql, docker

I was trying to run wordpress with postgres using the [pg4wp plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postgresql-for-wordpress/). In the docker logs, it shows:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in Standard input code on line 22

MySQL Connection Error: (2006) MySQL server has gone away
```

The docker commands I used were:

For setting up postgres:

`docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=securepassword -e POSTGRES_DB=abcd --name postgresql-wordpress -v "$PWD/database":/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:latest`

For setting up wordpress:

`docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=securepassword -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=abcd -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=<postgres_container_ip>:5432 --link=postgresql-wordpress:postgresql --name wordpress -p 80:80 -v "$PWD/html":/var/www/html -d wordpress`

After that, I followed the installation instructions here: [pg4wp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postgresql-for-wordpress/). The Wordpress installation page doesn't show up.

Comment: Are you sure that plugin works with your wordpress version? It looks really outdated.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like either I will have to use an older version of wordpress to use this plugin or use mysql.

Comment: @hvardhan any luck with it by any chance? I'm bumping into the same error

Comment: @StefanoMessina ended up using mariaDB

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the WP4PG published in the official plugin is not under maintenance.
Please try the following two.

There is a plugin that I forked and fixed in github.
https://github.com/kevinoid/postgresql-for-wordpress

Or there is a plugin redeveloping WP 4 PG called WPPG plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wppg/